# Write to a excel a tuple inside a list ,which is inside another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, nested-lists, xlsxwriter

Final, comes the time to write all my data which i have in lists to an excel file. The situation is like this:

I  have some random lists and one list have the below form:

**[[('visible', 2.5, 3.1, 'food')], [('hidden', 2.1, None, None),('hidden',5.2, 3.1, None),.....], [ ],........]**

**It is tuples inside list which inside another list.**

My code will check for 3 main conditions and write something in excel.
I have done the below code and it looks that it works until **else condition**( not sure if elif condition works 100% yet).

Οbviously I try to get the data inside that  complicate list with 
ineffective way

```
def write_captions_to_excel_file(self, randomlistone, randomlisttwo, comparelists):
print('writing to excel')
workbook = Workbook(os.path.join(description_path, 'all_captions.xlsx'))
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Images')  # 3 --> row number, column number, value
worksheet.write(row, 1, 'Title')
worksheet.write(row, 2, 'Market')
worksheet.write(row, 3, 'Price')
worksheet.write(row, 4, 'Offer')
worksheet.write(row, 5, 'Info')
worksheet.write(row, 6, 'Visibility')
worksheet.write(row, 7, 'Group Id')
row += 1

for index, comparelist in enumerate(comparelists):
    if len(comparelist) == 0:   #    examble [...[].....]
        pass
    elif len(comparelist) == 1:    #   examble  [[('nana', 2.3, 3.3, 'gift')]]
        worksheet.write(row, 0, randomlistone[index])  # 3 --> row number, column number, value
        worksheet.write(row, 1, randomlisttwo[index])
        worksheet.write(row, 2, comparelist[0][0])  #   write nana
        worksheet.write(row, 3, comparelist[0][1])   #  write 2.3
        worksheet.write(row, 6, 'visible'))
        if comparelist[0][2] is not None:   #  check  if   3.3 exist
            worksheet.write(row, 4, comparelist[0][2])  #   write 3.3
            worksheet.write(row, 5, comparelist[0][3])   #   write gift
        row += 1
    else:
        worksheet.write(row, 0, randomlistone[index])  # 3 --> row number, column number, value
        worksheet.write(row, 1, randomlisttwo[index])
        worksheet.write(row, 6, 'visible'))
        worksheet.write(row, 7, 'grouped' + str(index))
        for x[2] in comparelist:   
            if x[2] is not None:  # check if data exist in some tuple of the mindle list
                worksheet.write(row, 5, x[3])
                pass
        row += 1
        for y in comparelist:   # examble [[('nana', 2.3, 3.3, 'gift'),('nano', 5.3, 4.3, None),.....('nani', 2.1, 0.9, 'cart')]]
            worksheet.write(row, 0, randomlistone[index])  # 3 --> row number, column number, value
            worksheet.write(row, 1, randomlisttwo[index])
            worksheet.write(row, 2, y[0])
            worksheet.write(row, 3, y[1])
            worksheet.write(row, 6, 'hidden'))
            worksheet.write(row, 7, 'simple')
            if comparelist[2] is not None:
                worksheet.write(row, 4, y[2])
                worksheet.write(row, 5, y[3])
            row += 1
workbook.close()
```

I will apreciate any help, Thank you

Comment: Your code will not work, you have **indentation errors** and **Unresolved reference 'x'**. [Edit] your code in Question for a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to get data from List_List_tuple item, the below code works well for me.

```
for index, comparelist in enumerate(comparelists):
if len(comparelist) == 0:   #    examble [...[].....]
    pass
elif len(comparelist) == 1:    #   examble  [[('nana', 2.3, 3.3, 'gift')]]
    worksheet.write(row, 0, randomlistone[index])  # 3 --> row number, column number, value
    worksheet.write(row, 1, randomlisttwo[index])
    worksheet.write(row, 2, comparelist[0][0])  #   write nana
    worksheet.write(row, 3, comparelist[0][1])   #  write 2.3
    worksheet.write(row, 6, 'visible'))
    if comparelist[0][2] is not None:   #  check  if   3.3 exist
        worksheet.write(row, 4, comparelist[0][2])  #   write 3.3
        worksheet.write(row, 5, comparelist[0][3])   #   write gift
    row += 1
else:
    worksheet.write(row, 0, randomlistone[index])  # 3 --> row number, column number, value
    worksheet.write(row, 1, randomlisttwo[index])
    worksheet.write(row, 6, 'visible'))
    worksheet.write(row, 7, 'grouped' + str(index))
    for i in comparelist:
        if i[2] is not None:
            worksheet.write(row, 5, i[3])
            pass
    row += 1
    for y in comparelist:   # examble [[('nana', 2.3, 3.3, 'gift'),('nano', 5.3, 4.3, None),.....('nani', 2.1, 0.9, 'cart')]]
        worksheet.write(row, 0, randomlistone[index])  # 3 --> row number, column number, value
        worksheet.write(row, 1, randomlisttwo[index])
        worksheet.write(row, 2, y[0])
        worksheet.write(row, 3, y[1])
        worksheet.write(row, 6, 'hidden'))
        worksheet.write(row, 7, 'simple')
        if y[2] is not None:
            worksheet.write(row, 4, y[2])
            worksheet.write(row, 5, y[3])
        row += 1
```